# How to make DOM changes done in plain JS available to a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am adding a row to a table with some form elements using plain JS as:

```
var newRow = firstRow.cloneNode(true);
table.appendChild(newRow);
var newRowCells = newRow.getElementsByTagName("td");
...
```

One of the elements in the row is a dropdown. I want the dropdown in this newly added row to respond to jQuery function that handles `$(#dropdown).change()`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Put the handler directly on the `table` instead of on the dropdown, and use delegation. Like this: `$(mytable).on("change", ".dropdown_class", function() { /*the handler*/ });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the row with an object [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You just need to enter the pure JS element object into `$()` and you're done.

```
$(newRow).find(".dropdown").change(dropHandler);
```

Notice I've changed *#dropdown* (an ID) to *.dropdown* (a class) because you can't give the same ID to several DOM elements.